# Discord.py music bot's play command throws a TypeError

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord import Intents
from discord import guild
from discord import permissions
from discord import member 
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.core import has_permissions
import DiscordUtils
from discord.user import User 

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents = intents)

 #['dislike_count']
 @client.command()
 async def join(ctx):
          voiceTrue = ctx.author.voice
if voiceTrue is None:
    return await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")
await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
await ctx.send('Joined your voice channel')

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
         voiceTrue = ctx.author.voice
mevoiceTrue = ctx.guild.me.voice

if voiceTrue is None:
    return await ctx.send('You are not in a voice channel')

if mevoiceTrue is None:
    return await ctx.send('I already left')
await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
await ctx.send('Left your voice channel')


@client.command()
async def play(ctx, *, url):
         player = music.get_player(guild_id = ctx.guild.id)
if not player:
    player = music.create_player(ctx, ffmpeg_error_betterfix=True)
if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
    await player.queue(url, search=True)
    song = await player.play()
    await ctx.send(f'Started playing{song.name}')

else:
    song = await player.queue(url, search=True)
    await ctx.send(f'Added {song.name} to the queue')
```

I have tried the above code, and this `TypeError` keeps popping up whenever I use the `play()` command:

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I was following [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1DKYyFniNk&t=372s) by
Glowstik, and it worked perfectly for him in the video. Any solutions?

Comment: Can you edit the traceback of the error in the question?

Comment: I too used this code once upon a time . First it worked fine but atlast this module begans to stops working properly. So i would suggest you to use some other modules and try to get rid of this module as long as you can

Comment: ok thanks i am now using discord.js to create my music bot